# Can I combine mapping of OneToOne and OneToMany?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'd like to create the following bidirectional mapping:

- a payment is always be assigned to only one account (assume that is true for this example) => OneToOne
- an account can have several payments assigned => OneToMany

Example:

```
class Account {
    @OneToMany
    List<Payments> payments;
}

class Payment {
   @OneToOne
   Account account;
}
```

Where is my error in reasoning here?

Comment: If many payments can be made for the same account, you probably need `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: This is not a bidirectional mapping and its manytoone relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The error in reasoning is in this sentence :

> a payment is always be assigned to only one account (assume that is true for this example) => OneToOne

A particular Payment always belongs to one Account (the instance variable `account`), but many Payment instances can be assigned to one Account instance. Thus `@ManyToOne`.

Another example and more explanation can be found [here.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne#Example_of_a_ManyToOne_relationship_database)